# Linked List is missing out nodes and reversing order when printing

Tags: c++, string, printing, linked-list, nodes

I'm creating a basic program that uses a Linked List and text file (to populate the Linked List) to perform some manipulation on the data.

I've setup what I think is a working Linked List structure and a 'working' but possibly inefficient way of reading the text file and placing the data into the linked list nodes.

When I read in the file I check to see whether what's being read is correct (by outputting to the screen) and then using an insertNode function I've created.

However, when I go to print the Linked List I some of the nodes aren't the data that is being read in and the order in which it's being printed is in reverse?

My program is quite large so I've only included the relevant functions (which I've edited down to basics) and text file / output.

---

**Text file:**

```
car,Ferarri,12.0,aa,3,1,1,true
car,Mercedes,8.0,bb,5,4,0,false
```

**Linked List when printed:**

```
car -6.27744e_066 8.0 -842150451 5 4 false
car -6.27744e_066 12.0 -842150451 3 1 true
```

It's almost printing the correct output, but the order is in reverse, the strings are coming out as negative integers and it's missing the maxLoad nodes. Can anyone see why?

---

### **Read File**

```
void readFile()
{
    string text;
    string temp; // Added this line
    node* newNode = new node;

    ifstream file;
    file.open("example.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        getline(file, temp);
        text = temp;

        string input = text;
        istringstream ss(input);
        string token;
        node* newNode = new node;

        int counter = 0;

        while (getline(ss, token, ','))
        {
            cout << token << '\n';
            newNode->rented = token;
            counter++;

            if (counter == 0)
            {
                newNode->make = token;
            }
            else if (counter == 1)
            {
                newNode->model = token;
            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                std::istringstream ss(token);
                ss >> newNode->engine;
            }
            else if (counter == 3)
            {
                newNode->registration = token;
            }
            else if (counter == 4)
            {
                std::istringstream ss(token);
                ss >> newNode->doors;
            }
            else if (counter == 5)
            {
                std::istringstream ss(token);
                ss >> newNode->passengers;
            }
            else if (counter == 6)
            {
                std::istringstream ss(token);
                ss >> newNode->maxload;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode->rented = token;
            }
        }
        list.insertNode(newNode);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

### **Insert Node**

```
void linkedList::insertNode(node* newNode)
{
    newNode->nextNode = head;
    head = newNode;
}
```

### **Printing List**

```
void linkedList::displayList()
{

    node* thisNode = head;

        do
        {
            cout << thisNode->make << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->model << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->engine << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->registration << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->doors << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->passengers << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->maxload << "\t";
            cout << thisNode->rented << "\t";
            cout << "\n\t";
            thisNode = thisNode->nextNode;

        } while (thisNode != NULL);

}
```

---

Comment: You treat the list as a *stack*, by adding all new nodes at the head of the list.

Comment: Aren't you prepending your data to the linked list instead of appending it? That would explains why your data is in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You only allocate a new node once, outside the read loop. Make sure to allocate a new one every time you insert. Also you are inserting new elements at the head of the list and not the tail - hence the reverse order.

Here's something to help you:

```
node dummy;
dummy.next = nullptr;
node* tail = &dummy;

while (getline(...))
{
    node* newNode = new node();
    // fill in data
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}

// list.head = dummy.next;
```